# Bootstrap 5 & Vanilla JS Fixing second Navbar on top when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have two navbars, the first one is for contact information and second one is the main navbar with menu links.

I want to make the second navbar fixed on top when scrolling using **vanilla JavaScript.**

**Here is a live demo on** **[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/QWGyWPq)**

**My Full Code :**

**JS, CSS and HTML  :**

```js
    (function () {
      'use strict'
      
      // for Off-Canvas Menu
      
      document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"]').addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector('.offcanvas-collapse').classList.toggle('open')
      })
    })()
```

```css
    @media (max-width: 991.98px) {
      .offcanvas-collapse {
        position: fixed;
        top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
        bottom: 0;
        left: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        overflow-y: auto;
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #343a40;
        transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
      }
      .offcanvas-collapse.open {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <header class="myheader">
    
    <!-- First Navbar -->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-info">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">First Navbar</span>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!-- Second Navbar -->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nav is wrapped with header. Try the below code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Fullscreen OwlCarousel2 with centered Bootstrap Tab.</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


<!-- First Navbar -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-info">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">First Navbar</span>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Second Navbar -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Second Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="container py-5">

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

<p class="lead">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

</main>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```